# Misidentified Copyright Takedown

Tags: copyright

I'm a full time youtuber and I recently received a copyright takedown that I am 99.9% sure is either a mistake or outright fraud.

I went through youtube's system to dispute the claim, but it was rejected twice.

The company filing the claim is listed as 'UMPG Publishing' (VCPMC_CS), and they are claiming ownership of "Hallo Main Theme Cover". (the actual copyright notification has this odd misspelling of Halo as "Hallo")

[image: image of takedown]

Halo and all of it's music is owned and published by Microsoft, and on their official website they state that it is okay to use the content from their games in youtube videos.
(https://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/rules) The claim also reports it as a "Cover" instead of as the actual song which is very odd.

I also looked on the UMPG music catalog for anything related to the Halo OST and found nothing: https://www.umusicpub.com/us/Digital-Music-Library/search/Hallo

I feel like I have every reason to doubt the validity of this claim, but if I file a counter notification I am opening my self up to a lawsuit. But I also don't think I can afford to just concede either. I post videos rather infrequently and spend up to a month working on each one. This video has already pulled a million views and if I just let this go I'll lose a lot of money.

I'm not certain what I should do. All my attempts to contact the company by phone or email have failed. What kind of trouble would I be in if I file a counter notification and they come after me?

Comment: You might try to find out about "UMPG Publishing". A Google search for the name (with quotes) produces a number of stories similar to yours. Given that the P in "UMPG" stands for "Publishing" this sounds suspect in itself. Try contacting the real UMPG and ask if they know anything about this.

Comment: I attempted to email UMPG weeks ago and got no response. I also tried their phones but it goes to an automated system that tells you to email them. Standard practice for these kinds of companies it seems.

Comment: As you say. But if it turned out that this really is UMPG and they did sue you, this lack of engagement would help your case. Just to be sure, post a letter to their registered address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you are inviting a lawsuit if you file a counter-notice. You are also correct that it might be a clerical error. Your attorney is the guy who recommends a best course of action for you. Part of the ensuing trouble would be the bill from your attorney.
If the copyright holder wins in court, they could recover from you based on actual damages, statutory damages, and profits under [17 U.S.C. §504](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/504). The first is how much they lost (e.g. via sales or licensing fees) from your infringement. The second is a fixed amount ranging from $200 to $150,000, depending, provided that the work is registered. It is more likely that your case would fall in the $200 category, given a mistaken belief that you had permission as *innocent infringement*. The last is about whatever profits you made from the infringement that exceeds the copyright holder's losses.

Incidentally, under the relevant provision, [17 USC 512(g)(2)(C)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/512#g_2), they will restore your material shortly after receiving the counter notification,

> unless its designated agent first receives notice from the person who
> submitted the notification under subsection (c)(1)(C) that such person
> has filed an action seeking a court order to restrain the subscriber
> from engaging in infringing activity relating to the material on the
> service provider’s system or network.

Notice that all that YT has to have done is *received* notification that a lawsuit was filed. The other party does not have to prove to the provider that they filed a lawsuit.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser. I did some more research and found the copyright registration number for Halo: Combat Evolved and the OST release for Halo 2. All of them fall under Microsoft. Is this rock solid evidence to base my case on?

Halo 2 OST - SR0000688310 / 2006-08-04 
Halo 1 Game - TX0005593817 / 2002-04-09

Comment: The evidence is good, but no evidence is rock solid without careful in-person professional scrutiny.

Comment: 200 is an *exception* from the 750$ basic price: it's for a special kind of infringement only.

Comment: The available evidence indicates that the special markdown price would be applicable here.

Comment: I'd phrase that as *could*, but I agree, that it could be a case of *innocent infringement*, which is the 200 $ exception afaik. Linked the relevant statute.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_Original_Soundtrack), "He [Martin O'Donnell] drew inspiration for the theme from The Beatles' "Yesterday".

UMG bought out EMI, including the Beatles back catalogue. So I assume the theory is that the Halo soundtrack is a 'cover' of "Yesterday", and Microsoft thus can't give you permission to use it.

The poor writing is probably because the DMCA takedowns are likely outsourced at very cheap rates. UMG do *a lot* of takedowns. So I think the claim is likely valid, or at least arguable.

Comment: That seems really far-fetched. Wouldn't they have to list the infringed content as a cover of "Yesterday" if this was what they are trying to do?